# Double parentheses of a function call？

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int aaa(char *f, ...)
{
    putchar(*f);    
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    aaa("abc");
    aaa("%dabc", 3); 
    aaa(("abc"));
    aaa(("%dabc", 3));
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering why the following lines:

```
    aaa("abc");
    aaa("%dabc", 3); 
    aaa(("abc"));
```

run without error, but the fourth line (seen below):

```
    aaa(("%dabc", 3));
```

generates the following errors:

> main.c:15:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'aaa' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> main.c:3:5: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type `int'

Comment: These are parentheses, not brackets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The statement

```
aaa(("%dabc", 3));
```

calls the function `aaa` with the argument `("%dabc", 3)` which returns the value `3`.

Look up the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for more information.

Comment: ... and `3` is not compatible with `char*` (the type of the first argument to `aaa`), so the compiler gives you a warning.

Comment: Why would someone write `aaa(("abc"))` anyway ? Is there some use to these double-paren ?

Comment: Sometimes you need an extra set of parens around an argument when invoking a macro, e.g. when that argument is itself a vararg parameter list to be subsequently passed to a vararg function. But I don't think  it ever makes sense to do this for a straight function call.

Comment: "when that argument is itself a vararg parameter list to be subsequently passed to a vararg function. " Could you give an example?

Comment: Typical example is a debug print macro, where you might pass a printf arg list as one parameter, e.g. `DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_LEVEL_1, ("%s = %d", "foo", foo));` where the `DEBUG_PRINT` macro is defined as `#define DEBUG_PRINT(level, args) if (level > gDebugLevel) printf args`

Answer (score 2):

Like in maths, the parentheses inside the function call are interpreted as grouping: e.g. `(1) * (2)` is the same as `1 * 2`, but `(1 + 2) * 3` is not the same as `1 + 2 * 3`.

In the first example `aaa(("abc"))`: the inside parentheses are evaluated first, but `("abc")` is the same as `"abc"`, so this is equivalent to just calling `aaa("abc");`.

In the second example `aaa(("abc",3))`: the inside expression is `("abc", 3)` i.e. the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) comes into play and `"abc"` is discarded, leaving `3` as the argument to `aaa`. The compiler is complaining because `3` has type `int` not `char*` so you aren't calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

the lvalue ("xxx", val) evaluates "xxx" and then val and results to the last value in the brackets, i.e. val.
the bracket in aaa(...) is the parameter.

Comment: i would remove my answer, Joachims answer is better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because the parameter being passed to the function is `("%dabc", 3)` which itself invokes the comma operator and returns the value of `3`.